# crossfilter how to simply get the sum total from the values in a group

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

Given a crossfilter group that reduce to a key-value pair of something like:

```
[
   { key: A, value: 75 },
   { key: B, value: 35 }
]
```

(pie chart type data), how to you go about getting the sum of the values (110 in this case)? is there a quick xfilter method I am unable to find?

[Example Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/knycsLLy/1/)

Comment: No, you just use Javascript to sum up the values. you could use `Array.reduce` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example) or if you are using d3, `d3.sum` is an easier option (https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#sum). If what you are really interested in is the total and you don't care about the individual values, you could also use Crossfilter's `dimension.groupAll`.

Comment: ugh...this has to be the worst question I have ever asked....but thanks all the same. forest for the trees moment.

Comment: Not a bad question at all. Glad you're on to another way of approaching it now!